# SCRIPT5: Access is denied. On IE while using parse.js

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, cross-browser, parse-platform

Hi I'm getting Below error on IE.
While uploading the image to parse.com.

It is Working fine in chrome and firefox and safari

working with jquery 1.10.0.js

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.8.min.js"></script>
```

Error at this below code snippet.

```
  **parseFile.save().then(function(data) {**
          console.log("success");
        }, function(error) {
            console.log("Error");
            console.log(error);
        });
```

**Error Console:**

[image: Error Description]

Comment: And what code is on this line? (you will probably need to download it to local, un-minify it and link to that)

Comment: This code regards to saving selected file in parse.com server by using parseFile.save() it will save the file and returns the file url this is used to overcome crossbrowser issue. As you suggested to store parse.js in local I have tried but no luck.. still getting the same error.

Comment: Sure, you will get the same error, but my point was if you could post the actual code the error reference to in the question so we can see if we can spot any cause.

Comment: Getting error parseFile.save().then(function(data) { on this line..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by commenting these lines in **Parse._ajax** method from **parse-1.2.8.js** js file

```
 if (typeof(XDomainRequest) !== "undefined") {
      return Parse._ajaxIE8(method, url, data)._thenRunCallbacks(options);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a really annoying bug (feature?) in IE that if you try to use parse.com (or any other similar technology) over HTTPS, but your site is on HTTP, you will get errors.

Every other browser works.

The only solution is to host your site using HTTPS if you want IE users to be able to use it.